# How to open multiple url-web-links via custom local .html?

Tags: javascript, html

Once upon a time I encountered a simple but efficent script that allows to paste copied links (line by line) into a box and then after pressing a button it opened all of the links (http://etc.etc) in a new tab.

Unfortunately I have deleted this gem.

Can you help me to make a simple local .html page where user could paste list of urls:

- http://url.one
- http://url.two

and after pressing a button it will open them url-s in a browser

thats what im looking for:
https://thewindowsclub-thewindowsclubco.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/urlopener.jpg

closest call is this;

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function open_win() {
> window.open("http://www.java2s.com/")
> window.open("http://www.java2s.com/")
> }
> </script>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form>
> <input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_win()">
> </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

instead of predefined URL-s user should be able to paste own links in form of list

Comment: I don't know if this is of any use, but (if you're not building something for others to use and simply want to be able to open multiple links at once yourself), this browser extension does something similar:  https://github.com/benblack86/linkclump

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but I'd bet $1.00 that they wanted a more specific question about a problem you encountered after trying to write the code yourself. (The best questions include details about the desired result, and contrast it with the problematic result produced by the existing code, using a "minimal, complete, and verifiable" example.) You can see more details here if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: someone wrote that code in another stackoverflow answer and of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To open a new tab, you would use the javascript command `window.open(url,'_blank');`, where the URL is a reference to the URL you'd like to open. Here's a refrence for [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

For your specific usecase, you'd want to create a HTML document with something like a `<textarea>` in it, and a submit button. You'd then take the text, split it into an array along newlines, (using [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)), then loop over the result and call the `window.open` function on each entry.

I hoped this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){

    var urls = document.getElementById("url").value.split(" ");
    console.clear();
    
    urls.forEach(function(element){
        console.log(element)
        window.open(element,'_blank');
    });
});
```

```html
<p>Insert your URl seperated by space </p>
<input type="text" id="url" value="https://www.google.se http://www.icefilms.info/" />

<input type="button" id="submit" value="open" />
```